# Using VBA in MS Access 2010 to set cell value in table

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to dynamically update a table cell value in a metadata table, which is to hold the names of 5 existing forms.  This table is used to set the *.Caption* property of 5 respective buttons on *frmMainMenu*, where each button will in turn open the proper table.

If the user renames one of the 5 forms, the *Caption* field (field's name is Caption) for the appropriate record in MainMenu metadata table must automatically update, so the frmMainMenu can then pull the form's new name and populate the button name with the new form name.

Current form names:
*frmBorrower
frmCDMedia,
frmOrders,
frmQuickSearchBorrower,
frmQuickSearchMedia,
frmMainMenu*

Each form except *frmMainMenu* has own class module, which assigns the form's name to a Public Variable *formPopA, formPopB ...formPopE* using following code:

```
Public Function MyNameA()
Form_frmMainMenu.formPopA = Me.Name
End Function
```

In *frmMainMenu* I have the following:

```
Public formPopA As String
Public formPopB As String
Public formPopC As String
Public formPopD As String
Public formPopE As String

Private Sub Form_Load()
NamePop.PopulateTablesWithFormNames
SetCaptions
End Sub

Private Sub SetCaptions()
mainVars.mainVarsi
End Sub
```

I then have 2 standard modules, *MainVars*, which assigns the value in the MainMenu table to the appropriate button in *frmMainMenu* (this is successful), and then *NamePop*, which is supposed to set the values of the table cells using user defined *PopulateTablesWithFormNames()*.

My problem code (I think) is in *NamePop*, where I cannot find a way to make *PopulateTablesWithFormNames* to assign the appropriate form name.

I have tried this:

```
Dim x As DAO.Database
Dim myX As DAO.Recordset
Set x = CurrentDb()
Set myX = x.OpenRecordset("MainMenu", dbOpenTable)
myX.FindFirst "ID = 1"
myX![Caption] = Form_frmMainMenu.formPopA
myX.Update
```

I understand there are significant differences between DAO, ADO and Access objects, but not how they work differently. I created all current objects with commands on the ribbon, however that makes a difference. Experience level with VBA novice.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems with your existing code:

First, you cannot perform `.FindFirst` on a Recordset that has been opened as `dbOpenTable`. If you try you'll get the error "Operation is not supported for this type of object.". You need to open the Recordset as `dbOpenDynaset`.

Second, with DAO you must invoke the `.Edit` method before trying to modify a record in the Recordset. If you omit that step then when you try to `.Update` you'll get the error "Update or CancelUpdate without AddNew or Edit.".

Try this code instead:

```vbs
Dim x As DAO.Database
Dim myX As DAO.Recordset
Set x = CurrentDb()
Set myX = x.OpenRecordset("MainMenu", dbOpenDynaset)
myX.FindFirst "ID = 1"
myX.Edit
myX![Caption] = Form_frmMainMenu.formPopA
myX.Update
```

Comment: Now when I open frmMainMenu (which, by the way, is not based on the table MainMenu, frmMainMenu was created first, then I was asked to create the metadata table) I get the following message:      An expression you entered is the wrong data type for one of the arguments.

Comment: When I set myX.[Caption] = 1 or myX.[Caption] = "Menu Name" it populates as it should, so now, how do I represent the string variable formPopA - E as a string that will be accepted by the assignment?